# Php echo json_encode array into javascript array

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to send a post to a php script which will collect all the account information from the database using this...

```
var e = document.getElementById("lstAccounts");
var accountID = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
alert("Account ID:"+accountID);
$.post("php/getAccount.php", {ID: accountID}, function(data)
{
    var accountInfo = data;
});
```

This posts into this...

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['ID'];
include('database_api.php');
$db = new DatabaseControl;
$db->open_connection();
$result = $db->db_query("SELECT * FROM tblAccount WHERE ID=$id");
$account_info = array();
//Get Basic Information
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $account_info['Name'] = $row['Name'];
    $account_info['CRN'] = $row['CRN'];
    $account_info['ID'] = $row['ID'];
    $account_info['Type'] = $row['Type'];
    $account_info['Revenue'] = $row['Revenue'];
    $account_info['Industry'] = $row['Industry'];
    $account_info['Description'] = $row['Description'];
    $account_info['Employees'] = $row['NoOfEmployees'];
    $account_info['Billing'] = $row['BillingAddress'];
    $account_info['Shipping'] = $row['ShippingAddress'];
}
//Get Details
$result = $db->db_query("SELECT tblDetails.ID, tblDetails.Label, tblDetails.Value FROM tblAccountDetails
                            INNER JOIN tblDetails ON tblDetails.ID = tblAccountDetails.DetailID
                            WHERE AccountID=$id");
//Get Basic Information
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $account_info['Detail'.$row['ID']]['Label'] = $row['Label'];
    $account_info['Detail'.$row['ID']]['Value'] = $row['Value'];
}
//Get Contact Information

//Get Invoices

//Get Payments

//Get Notes

//Get To-Do

//Events

//Send back to javascript
echo json_encode($account_info);
?>
```

I need the echoed json_encode to enter a javascript on the return data. How do I get that data into an array?

```
$.post("php/getAccount.php", {ID: accountID}, function(data)
{
    //In here how do I decode data into a javascript array
});
```

The data is set at "{"Name":"A business name","CRN":null,"ID":"17","Type":"User","Revenue":null,"Industry":"Software & Internet","Description":null,"Employees":null,"Billing":"An Address","Shipping":"An Address","Detail75":{"Label":"Phone","Value":"a phone number"},"Detail76":{"Label":"Email","Value":"an email address"}}" on return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass in [json_encode()](http://www.php.net/json_encode)'ed data from your php, like:

```
...
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $account_info['Detail'.$row['ID']]['Label'] = $row['Label'];
    $account_info['Detail'.$row['ID']]['Value'] = $row['Value'];
}
echo json_encode($account_info);
```

in js part:

```
$.post("php/getAccount.php", {ID: accountID}, function(data) {
    //parse the json response
    var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    console.log(response); //you can use $.each to iterate the data
});
```

Comment: @TomHanson you're welcome.. Btw, you could mark it as Accepted Answer if it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

First Set the datatype as `JSON`

```
$.post("php/getAccount.php", {ID: accountID}, function(data)
{

    // Confirm Response
    console.log(data);
    $.each(data, function(i, e){
       console.log(e);
    });
}, 'json');
```